# Shortest invariant meeting point on the directed graph with loops

Tags: python, algorithm

I have directed graph with loops. Here is the example:

```py
{
 0: [1,2],
 1: [1,3],
 2: [3],
 3: [4],
 4: []
}
```

- Edge 0 flows into 1 and 2
- Edge 1 flows into itself and into 3
- Edge 2 flows into 3
- And edge 3 flows into edge 4 (without any reason so much)

If some imagionary actor will stand on the edge 0, and will start moving, no matter what he will arive to the edge 3 (let's ignore infinite loops).

Is there an algorithm, where it is possible to supply such graph with some edge (0 from example), and it will give me shortest invariant meeting point (3 from example)?

Comment: The meaning of "shortest" and "invariant" is not clear here.

Comment: I just interpret this as "Find a vertex with zero out-degree which is reachable from all other vertices" If that is so, it should be no-brainer I guess. Let us know what you've tried and add some more examples that help us understand "shortest" and "invariant".

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni "Find a vertex with zero out-degree" is wrong. In example I showed that 3 is the answer, which is not "zero out-degree". "reachable from all other vertices" is wrong too. 3 is not reachable from 4 in example. Also I showed that we can place an imagionary actor, which is able to go from a given position (0, we have this condition, right?). And no matter what actor will come to (3), because there is no way actor won't come there (except infinite loops, which I told to ignore).

Comment: And the aim is to find that meeting point. I am not sure what is unclear there.

Comment: Then the example of graph you gave is using different notation. Usually 0: [1,2] means there is a directed edge from 0 to 1 and 0 to 2.

Comment: "meeting point" who all is meeting where? A diagram would help. On what basis you define something as "shortest"?

Comment: So in your example, both 3 and 4 are meeting points but 3 is  the correct answer because on any path from 0 to 4, 3 occurs before. Is that correct?

Comment: @shridhar-r-kulkarni If some actor will go from a given point, which we supply (0 in example), it will be able to traverse the graph. In example there are mostly 2 ways to do that: 0-1-3-4, 0-2-3-4 (also 0-1-1-1-3-4 and similar, but we are ignoring it). No matter what imagionary actors will meet at point 3 first, due there is no other way. So I asked about the algorithm to find that "invariant" (which is 3) point of meeting of these imagionary actors.

Comment: @qouify Kinda. I think getting only 3 would be okay (maybe better, not sure), due 4 follows 3, and there is no way go to get to 4 before 3.

Comment: What if the imaginary actor starts on 4? It can't meet at 3

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I told that it is needed to supply some start point. And example was for 0, not for 4. No doubt if start point is 4, there won't be a meeting point.

Comment: Why not do BFS from set of starting points and see where they all meet? That will be shortest meeting point.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I am not sure what set of start points I should use, because algorithm must accept graph and only one starting point as input. Can you explain a little bit more in details?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Also I tried to traverse the graph somehow by myself, but my naive approaches did not work somehow. I guess, I am not so clever :(

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Also I tried this with a graph, which is very big, which has a lot of loops (and everything is interconnected), and there could be found short paths for meeting point if you go in one direction and very long if you go to another direction, so I am not sure if BFS should work (maybe I am wrong, not sure).

Comment: If only one starting point is being input, then who all are supposed to meet at the starting point? I think you should post a couple of more examples, their inputs and outputs. If possible draw and post the graphs too. Please do this so that you get the clarity about the question and we can get it too. Easy way you can quote the source of the problem so that we can read about it in detail. I am guessing this is going to end up with a simple BFS. Post an example that can't be solved with BFS.

Comment: "who all are supposed to meet at the starting point". Actors, who are going all possible directions in all possible ways from the given point, which have to cross one single point no matter what, because they have no way around. What is not clear?

Comment: And they do not meet at start point, they go out from the start point and meet at the meeting point, which must be found...

Comment: Can you get the end point as an input? for example 4 in your example?? And could you show me a more complex example. I need to test my method.

Comment: @MajidHajibaba It is ok to get any point as input practicly on any graph (so 4 is ok). If it is 4, I expect that there is no solution. About other examples: I am just not sure what to post. Graph I am trying to "solve" has around 500 000 vertices. So, not gonna post ot. Only important stuff is: "Directed cycle graph" is used.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, the following algorithm can handle your request. However, it may not be the efficient algorithm which may you find.

```
get g as DAG (Directed and Asyclic)
get s as start node
get d as destination node

arr(paths) <= find All Paths From s to d 

if(paths.size <=1) print("There is no meeting point")

intersects = paths[0]

for(int i=1; i< paths.size(); i++) { 
    intersetcs <= find intersection nodes between paths i and intersects 
}

foreach (node: intersects) {
    if(node has no outgoing)
        intersects.remove(node);
}

print(intersects)
```

output of program for your example:

```
path 0 : [0, 1, 3, 4]
path 1 : [0, 2, 3, 4]
meeting points: [0, 3]
```

another output of program:

```
g:{
 0: [1,2],
 1: [3,4],
 2: [3,4],
 3: [5],
 4: [5],
 5: [6,7],
 6: [],
 7: []
}
s=0, d=7

path 0: [0, 1, 3, 5, 7]
path 1: [0, 1, 4, 5, 7]
path 2: [0, 2, 3, 5, 7]
path 3: [0, 2, 4, 5, 7]
meeting points: [0, 5]
```

At last an example without meeting points:

```
g:{
 0: [1,2],
 1: [2,3],
 2: [5],
 3: [4],
 4: [5],
 5: []
}

s=0, d=5
path 0: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
path 1: [0, 1, 2, 5]
path 2: [0, 2, 5]
meeting points: [0]
```

I provide you an example in Java too based this algorithm.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

// A directed graph using
// adjacency list representation
public class Graph {

    // No. of vertices in graph
    private int v;

    // adjacency list
    private ArrayList<Integer>[] adjList;

    // Constructor
    public Graph(int vertices)
    {

        // initialise vertex count
        this.v = vertices;

        // initialise adjacency list
        initAdjList();
    }

    // utility method to initialise
    // adjacency list
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initAdjList()
    {
        adjList = new ArrayList[v];

        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            adjList[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    // add edge from u to v
    public void addEdge(int u, int v)
    {
        // Add v to u list.
        adjList[u].add(v);
    }

    // Prints all paths from
    // s to d
    public void printAllPaths(int s, int d)
    {
        boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[v];
        ArrayList<Integer> pathList = new ArrayList<>();

        // add source to path[]
        pathList.add(s);

        // Call recursive utility
        printAllPathsUtil(s, d, isVisited, pathList);
    }

    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    private void printAllPathsUtil(Integer u, Integer d, boolean[] isVisited, List<Integer> localPathList)
    {

        if (u.equals(d)) {
            //System.out.println(localPathList);
            allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(localPathList));
            // if match found then no need to traverse more till depth
            return;
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = true;

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to current vertex
        for (Integer i : adjList[u]) {
            if (!isVisited[i]) {
                // store current node in path[]
                localPathList.add(i);
                printAllPathsUtil(i, d, isVisited, localPathList);

                // remove current node in path[]
                localPathList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = false;
    }


    // Driver program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a sample graph
        Graph g = new Graph(6);
        /*g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);*/

        g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 5);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);
        g.addEdge(4, 5);
        // arbitrary source
        int s = 0;

        // arbitrary destination
        int d = 5;
        System.out.println(
                "Following are all different paths from "
                        + s + " to " + d);
        g.printAllPaths(s, d);

        System.out.println(g.allPaths);
        findMeetingPoint(g);

        /*for (int d=0; d<=4; d++) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Following are all different paths from "
                            + s + " to " + d);
            g.printAllPaths(s, d);
        }*/
    }

    private static void findMeetingPoint(Graph g) {
        if(g.allPaths.size()<=1) {
            System.out.println("No meeting point");
            return;
        }
        Set<Integer> intersects = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> meetPoints = new HashSet<>();

        intersects.addAll(g.allPaths.get(0));

        for(int i=1; i<g.allPaths.size(); i++) {
            intersects.retainAll (g.allPaths.get(i));
        }

        for (Integer node: intersects) {
            if(g.adjList[node].size()==0)
                intersects.remove(node);
        }

        System.out.println(intersects);


    }
}
```

**EDITTED 1 :**

code which can handle cycles:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

// A directed graph using
// adjacency list representation
public class Graph {

    // No. of vertices in graph
    private int v;

    // adjacency list
    private ArrayList<Integer>[] adjList;

    // Constructor
    public Graph(int vertices)
    {

        // initialise vertex count
        this.v = vertices;

        // initialise adjacency list
        initAdjList();
    }

    // utility method to initialise
    // adjacency list
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initAdjList()
    {
        adjList = new ArrayList[v];

        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            adjList[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    // add edge from u to v
    public void addEdge(int u, int v)
    {
        // Add v to u list.
        if(u != v)
            adjList[u].add(v);
    }

    // Prints all paths from
    // s to d
    public void printAllPaths(int s, int d)
    {
        boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[v];
        ArrayList<Integer> pathList = new ArrayList<>();

        // add source to path[]
        pathList.add(s);

        // Call recursive utility
        printAllPathsUtil(s, d, isVisited, pathList);
    }

    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    private void printAllPathsUtil(Integer u, Integer d, boolean[] isVisited, List<Integer> localPathList)
    {

        if (u.equals(d)) {
            System.out.println(localPathList);
            allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(localPathList));
            // if match found then no need to traverse more till depth
            return;
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = true;

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to current vertex
        for (Integer i : adjList[u]) {
            if (!isVisited[i]) {
                // store current node in path[]
                localPathList.add(i);
                printAllPathsUtil(i, d, isVisited, localPathList);

                // remove current node in path[]
                localPathList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = false;
    }


    // Driver program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a sample graph
        Graph g = new Graph(5);
        g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 1);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);

       /* g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 5);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);
        g.addEdge(4, 5);*/
        // arbitrary source
        int s = 0;

        // arbitrary destination
        int d = 4;
        System.out.println(
                "Following are all different paths from "
                        + s + " to " + d);
        g.printAllPaths(s, d);
        findMeetingPoint(g);

        //System.out.println(g.allPaths);

        /*for (int d=0; d<=4; d++) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Following are all different paths from "
                            + s + " to " + d);
            g.allPaths.clear();
            g.printAllPaths(s, d);
            findMeetingPoint(g);
        }*/
    }

    private static void findMeetingPoint(Graph g) {
        if(g.allPaths.size()<=1) {
            System.out.println("No meeting point");
            return;
        }
        Set<Integer> intersects = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> meetPoints = new HashSet<>();

        intersects.addAll(g.allPaths.get(0));

        for(int i=1; i<g.allPaths.size(); i++) {
            intersects.retainAll (g.allPaths.get(i));
        }

        for (Integer node: intersects) {
            if(g.adjList[node].size()==0)
                intersects.remove(node);
        }

        System.out.println("Meeting points: " + intersects);


    }
}
```

**EDITTED 2 :**

code which can handle cycles and without a defined destination:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

// A directed graph using
// adjacency list representation
public class Graph {

    // No. of vertices in graph
    private int v;

    // adjacency list
    private ArrayList<Integer>[] adjList;

    // Constructor
    public Graph(int vertices)
    {

        // initialise vertex count
        this.v = vertices;

        // initialise adjacency list
        initAdjList();
    }

    // utility method to initialise
    // adjacency list
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initAdjList()
    {
        adjList = new ArrayList[v];

        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            adjList[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    // add edge from u to v
    public void addEdge(int u, int v)
    {
        // Add v to u's list.
        if(u != v)
            adjList[u].add(v);
    }

    // Prints all paths from
    // 's' to 'd'
    public void printAllPaths(int s)
    {
        boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[v];
        ArrayList<Integer> pathList = new ArrayList<>();

        // add source to path[]
        pathList.add(s);

        // Call recursive utility
        printAllPathsUtil(s, isVisited, pathList);
    }

    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    private void printAllPathsUtil(Integer u, boolean[] isVisited, List<Integer> localPathList)
    {

        if (adjList[u].isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(localPathList);
            allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(localPathList));
            // if match found then no need to traverse more till depth
            return;
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = true;

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to current vertex
        for (Integer i : adjList[u]) {
            if (!isVisited[i]) {
                // store current node in path[]
                localPathList.add(i);
                printAllPathsUtil(i, isVisited, localPathList);

                // remove current node in path[]
                localPathList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = false;
    }


    // Driver program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a sample graph
        Graph g = new Graph(8);
        /*g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 1);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);*/

        /*g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 5);
        g.addEdge(3, 4);
        g.addEdge(4, 5);*/

        g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 3);
        g.addEdge(1, 4);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(2, 4);
        g.addEdge(3, 5);
        g.addEdge(4, 5);
        g.addEdge(5, 6);
        g.addEdge(5, 7);

        // arbitrary source
        int s = 0;

        // arbitrary destination
        System.out.println(
                "Following are all different paths from "
                        + s );
        g.printAllPaths(s);
        findMeetingPoint(g);
    }

    private static void findMeetingPoint(Graph g) {
        if(g.allPaths.size()<=1) {
            System.out.println("No meeting point");
            return;
        }
        Set<Integer> intersects = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> meetPoints = new HashSet<>();

        intersects.addAll(g.allPaths.get(0));

        for(int i=1; i<g.allPaths.size(); i++) {
            intersects.retainAll (g.allPaths.get(i));
        }

        for (Integer node: intersects) {
            if(g.adjList[node].size()==0)
                intersects.remove(node);
        }

        System.out.println("Meeting points: " + intersects);

    }
}
```

input as:

```
g:{
 0: [1,2],
 1: [1,3,4],
 2: [3,4],
 3: [5],
 4: [5],
 5: [6,7],
 6: [],
 7: []
}
s=0
```

and output as:

```
Following are all different paths from 0
[0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 7]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 7]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 7]
[0, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 4, 5, 7]
Meeting points: [0, 5]
```

You can use [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/) which provide Python code to find all paths, but need change like the proposed algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution! Just want to ask about cycles. I wrote that there are loops in the graph. So it should be a "Directed cycle graph" (I guess, it is not the hardest thing to fix). Also didn't check how code works yet, but can you tell the difficulty of the algorithm in big O notation? I just afraid that it will explode in my case, due it can be toooo many possible paths in 500 000 vertices. If we are gonna search every path, difficulty can probably be bigger than O(n)^2 (whatever n is here)? Not sure yet. Checking out the solution (Need some time to find a JAVA compiler :).

Comment: Also a quick question. In the java code there is "arbitrary destination", which is "int d = 5". But in my case, I can only supply "arbitrary source" point. can  "arbitrary destination" be removed from the current version of the algorithm?

Comment: Checked out the running code. "arbitrary destination" should not exist. Only graph and source are acceptable as input :(

Comment: Hi. Time complexity is O(n2) not more. You can remove arbitrary destination and use it for each destination. But needs to know where is the end of Graph. See my commented code `for (int d=0; d<=4; d++)` .

Comment: So, it does not work if there are cycles in the graph? In my case there are lots of cycles and some "ends" too.

Comment: Since you say ` we are ignoring it` I ignore it. You can test the code in online compiler. We can add cycles easily. let me try it.

Comment: We ignore, but not remove them :D

Comment: I just do not want to care about cases where actor is going forever.

Comment: I edit code. Cycles don't play a role in path finding. I can provide you python code for path finding but need to extend like the proposed algorithm to find intersects.

Comment: It would be actually very cool! I am still checking out the code. Little bit not used to read java, but online compiler saves me.  Also, as I get, in the case of not specifying "destination point" (my case), it is needed to printAllPaths for every point as it shown in the commented code?

Comment: I edited code to remove "destination point".

Comment: Testing out the code. I guess, It is needed to remove recursion (at least from my side). printAllPathsUtil is just exploding instantly :'o

Comment: Read the document I sent to you carefully. It's based divide and conquer and time complexity is not more than O(n^2). There are plenty of algorithms with recursion and time O(n^2). you can read fibunatchi how implement by recursion or for loop.

Comment: Will try to increase recursion limit. Maybe will help and not critical, lol

Comment: I guess, everything is going great, but my graph is super big. Depressing. System is out of memory, lol. I am curious if it there is a way how to improve this algorithm :') I was thinking about time consuming algos, but I am too stupid.

Comment: You can use dynamic programming instead of recursion. may helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241007/discussion-between-majid-hajibaba-and-cppcppcppcppcppcppcppcppcppcpp).